# clean urls with router.push in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js, push, router

I have the code below. It redirects to /home and passes a username variable. However, in the address bar, it shows http://localhost:3000/home?username=bobmarley. How can I pass variables using next.js cleanly?

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
loginUser(this.state.user)
        .then(response => {
          var username = response['username'];

          if (username) {
            this.props.router.push({
              pathname: '/home',
              query: { username: username }
            });
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `as` prop of [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush), this will be what is displayed in the address bar. Set it to the same value used for `pathname`.

> `as` - Optional decorator for the URL that will be shown in the browser.

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/home',
  as: '/home',
  query: { username: username }
});
```

Comment: Hey I did this and I still got the username in my url bar?

Answer (score 0):

This is not where you put the as parameter.
It should look like

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/home',
  query: { username: username }
},
{
pathname: '/masked-url'
});
```